# Making msi in cx freeze - module in reportlab

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-freeze, reportlab

I am trying to make a distributable python script in cx_freeze. When I run it, I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named lib
```

The referenced line in my program is

```
from reportlab.lib import colors, utils
```

I did not specify packages in my setup.py. This particular program's output is a pdf report that's written in Reportlab. I also use PyQt4, matplotlib, numpy, and mpl_toolkits. In most of these, I import specific modules. Is there a way to change the packages? Or any other way to do what I want? The goal is an installable program so that a co-worker can generate reports in my absence without going through actually installing Python and accoutrements.

---

ETA

Here is my setup.py:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os",'sys', 'PyQt4','reportlab', 'csv', 'numpy', 'matplotlib']}


if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

setup(  name = "XY grouped plots",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Contact <myworkemail> with questions",
        options = {"build_exe" : build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("XY_grouped_plots.pyw", base=base)])
```

And here are the imports I use in my program:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtGui import *   #yes, I know this should be covered above
from PyQt4.QtCore import * #but for some reason when I only do that, it gives me errors. 
from reportlab.lib import colors, utils
import csv
import numpy as np
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, landscape
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, Image, PageBreak, KeepTogether
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle as PS
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_CENTER
from reportlab.platypus.paragraph import Paragraph
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
```

and here is the error I got when I added the packages as above:

```
raise ImportError("No module named %r" %subModuleName)
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.uic.port_v3.proxy_base'
```

Are my imports too broad? When I let cx_freeze choose imports, I had that problem with reportlab (and no errors when I was building the msi file). Now it's throwing this error when I'm trying to make the msi file.

Answer (score 1):

I happened this question, after I remove 'PyQt4' from packages ,build success!